# Azure REST API in Check_mk

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, check-mk

I was wondering what approach should I take to run my own API request for checkmk. I have already tested retrieving data quota usage information.

Thank you in advanced

Kind regards

I already searched on checkmk site:-

```json
{

  "unit":"Bytes"
  "nextResetTime" : "9999-12-31T23:59:59.999999z"
  "currentValue": 14725120,
  "limit": 5368701200,
  "name" : {
          "value" : "FileSystemStorage",
          "localizedValue": "File System Storage"
   }
}


],
"nextLink" : null,
"id" : null 

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code to call an API with ***python inside the VM or host*** that runs your **`checkmk site`**:-

To call a **`checkmk API` with *authorization***, ***Refer the code below***:-

```py
import requests


api_token = 'your_api_token_or_username_password'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Token {api_token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}


endpoint_url = 'https://your_checkmk_instance/api/endpoint'
response = requests.get(endpoint_url, headers=headers)


if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    print(data)
else:
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
```

Code with a API without any authorization:-

```py
import requests

# Make API request
endpoint_url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'
response = requests.get(endpoint_url)

# Check if request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse JSON response
    data = response.json()
    # Process data as needed
    print(data)
else:
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
```

***Output:-***

[image]

***Also, as an alternative you can directly monitor an Azure service:-***

According to this [**Checkmk Official document**](https://docs.checkmk.com/latest/en/monitoring_azure.html), You need to implement authentication for your Rest API through Azure AD by referring this Document:-

In your Azure AD create a new application/service principal for Azure AD like below:-

[image]

Then assign this application role to access the File storage by assigning it Contributor role on the Azure storage account that contains your File share or at the Subscription level:-

***Azure storage account level:-***

[image]

[image]

***Azure Subscription level for the access to all the storage account in multiple resource groups:-***

[image]

Now create a **Client Secret** for your **Azure AD app** and then

navigate to ***`Setup > Agents > VM, Cloud, Container > Microsoft Azure`***, and establish a rule that specifically targets the newly created Azure host. And add the above ***Application Subscription Id, Tenant ID, Client ID and Client Secret:-*** and implement the testing of Azure resource monitoring according to the document above.

You can also use the above application's parameters in postman or by curl like below:-

Create a ***Post request*** to **obtain access token** for the ***checkmk api***:-

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/YOUR_TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

And then call the ***checkmk API*** with the Access Token above, Given you have added the checkmk API as an API app and provided API permissions to the App above.